# Why I am getting wrong answer in Juypter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying random stuff in my juypter notebook and got this output.

Can any one please explain why am I getting '150.95600000000002' instead of '150.956'. ?

```
a = 100.5
b = 50.456
var1 = a + b
print(var1)
```

> output I am getting: 150.95600000000002
> output should be : 150.956

I was adding two float variables using some third variable and output which I expected is totally different from which I got.

Comment: It's not totally different from what you got, of course.  It is the same number, within the precision of the computer.  There are ways to DISPLAY it so the result doesn't confuse you.